# What is the recommended way to use Vim folding for Python code?

Tags: python, vim, folding

I am interested in enabling code folding in Vim for Python code. I have noticed multiple ways to do so.

Does anyone have a preferred way to do Python code folding in Vim? I.e,

- Do you have a particular Vim plugin that you use and like?
- Do you use manual folding or do you place markers in comments?
- Any other recommended ways to do code folding for Python in Vim?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Personally I can't convince myself to litter my code with the markers. I've become pretty used to (and efficient) at using indent-folding. Together with my mapping of space bar (see below) to open/close folds and the zR and zM commands, I'm right at home. Perfect for Python!

```
set foldmethod=indent
nnoremap <space> za
vnoremap <space> zf
```

This maps the spacebar to open/close the current indented fold in normal mode. It also maps the spacebar to create a manual fold in visual mode. However, this doesn't work if foldmethod is set to indent so its purpose is a mystery.

Comment: :set foldmethod=indent first. I was googling for just this and stumbled upon your answer, very nice! :)

Comment: My friend also liked `set foldnestmax=2`, this way the methods of classes are folded, but internal statements aren't.

Comment: I'm not certain why the second mapping is in this answer to zf.  It's not used if indent-folding is being used.  However, if you are doing manual folding the mapping makes perfect sense.  za, however, seems to be the best way to open/close folds quickly.  I also recommend using fold navigation (zk, zj).

Comment: The vnoremap is good for manual mapping.  In your ftplugin, add set foldmethod=indent for Python.  Then, in your .vimrc, set foldmethod=manual.  Now, you can fold in both Python and non-Python with spacebar mapping

Answer (score 25):

I use [this](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2462) syntax file for Python. It sets the folding method to syntax and folds all classes and functions, but nothing else.

Comment: how to fold after unfolding? I cant find the shortcut! tnx

Comment: Tried this syntax file and it worked reasonably well for the highlighting. But it did absolutely nothing for the cold folding, when i use 'zM' nothing happens, when i use 'za' in a class i get the E490 (No Fold found). What is going wrong?

Comment: +1. At first try, python code (class, method) folding works wonderfully for me. Employ Walter's (http://stackoverflow.com/a/360634/605356) answers to map space bar to fold commands, but that solution doesn't work nearly as well (for me) as this one. Thanks @Tomas for the reference.

Comment: @DaniGehtdichnixan, perhaps you need :AnsiEsc -- look into that and I think you will find a solution

Answer (score 12):

Yet another plugin for folding Python code. Rather simple, handling docstrings, and on the GitHub:

[SimpylFold](https://github.com/tmhedberg/SimpylFold)

Enjoy!

Comment: This works best. I have stopped thinking about code folding at all since it has never caused any headache.

Comment: @iankit I sometimes wish it would also fold `if`, `for` and `while` blocks, do you not?

Comment: hmm that might not be very helpful i think. If he folds these blocks, it is not very clear what the content is while in a folded state. However with methods and other named blocks the name tells it all. I can sort of guess what the folded block is doing by looking at its name.

Comment: @iankit I don't know.. I'd like to try. Why not [trying](https://github.com/tmhedberg/SimpylFold/issues/67)? ^ ^

Answer (score 7):

Python is well suited for folding on indent, bit for writing my own code I use markers as they can crunch a document down the way you want it and can serve as a kind of a table of contents. I have this in my vimrc to flip between the two when I'm viewing someone elses code.

```
#Toggle fold methods \fo
let g:FoldMethod = 0
map <leader>fo :call ToggleFold()<cr>
fun! ToggleFold()
    if g:FoldMethod == 0
        exe 'set foldmethod=indent'
        let g:FoldMethod = 1
    else
        exe 'set foldmethod=marker'
        let g:FoldMethod = 0
    endif
endfun
#Add markers (trigger on class Foo line)
nnoremap ,f2 ^wywO#<c-r>0 {{{2<esc>
nnoremap ,f3 ^wywO#<c-r>0 {{{3<esc> 
nnoremap ,f4 ^wywO#<c-r>0 {{{4<esc>
nnoremap ,f1 ^wywO#<c-r>0 {{{1<esc>
```

Answer (score 6):

I really like the [`python_ifold` plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2002).

Comment: Unfortunately, this plugin uses more processor time than I would prefer (even with the a version) as I like to keep my vim speedy.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: This answer really needs a description.

Answer (score 4):

In your `.vimrc`:

```
set foldmethod=indent
set shiftwidth=4
```

Then `zM` to mask all `zR` to expand all. I also added:

```
nnoremap <space> za
vnoremap <space> zf
map z1  :set foldlevel=0<CR><Esc>
map z2  :set foldlevel=1<CR><Esc>
map z3  :set foldlevel=2<CR><Esc>
map z4  :set foldlevel=3<CR><Esc>
map z5  :set foldlevel=4<CR><Esc>
map z6  :set foldlevel=5<CR><Esc>
map z7  :set foldlevel=6<CR><Esc>
map z8  :set foldlevel=7<CR><Esc>
map z9  :set foldlevel=8<CR><Esc>
```

So you can `z1` and `z2` to unindent little by little.

Answer (score 3):

For me the ideal folding is to fold just the `class` and `def` blocks, indent folding is too much for my taste. I think one elegant solution is to use the syntax system like this [one](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2462) mentioned by Tomas. However, this one is meant to replace the original syntax file and it may end being older than the original (i.e. that script doesn't mention Python 3 syntax).

My solution is to place in the `~/.vim/syntax` folder a file named `python.vim` with just the important lines (taken from the above script):

```
syn match   pythonDefStatement  /^\s*\%(def\|class\)/
       \ nextgroup=pythonFunction skipwhite
syn region  pythonFunctionFold  start="^\z(\s*\)\%(def\|class\)\>"
       \ end="\ze\%(\s*\n\)\+\%(\z1\s\)\@!." fold transparent

hi link pythonDefStatement Statement
```

Then simply activate the folding with `:set foldmethod=syntax`.

Comment: I like this solution. But it does not match 'n fold `class`es and `def`s if they stand at the beginning of a line. Since I can hardly read the expression, I am in trouble trying to tweak it in order to match `^def` and `^class`. This is curious though since `\s*` should deal well with this..

Answer (score 2):

I really like this little vim script i wrote for .vimrc. It maps `alt+1` to fold the first python indent level (class definitions and functions), `alt+2` to fold the second level (class methods), and `alt+0` to unfold everything. It makes sure it only folds one level and doesn't fold any of the nested sub levels. You can still use `za` to toggle folding for the current block. Note that in `^[0`, the `^[` is `alt` for my terminal. Don't have a lot of experience in vim script so feel free to make suggestions on the function :)

```
" Python folding
nnoremap ^[0 zR<CR>
nnoremap ^[1 :call Fold(0)<CR>
nnoremap ^[2 :call Fold(1)<CR>
function Fold(level)
    :let b:max = a:level + 1
    :set foldmethod=indent
    :execute 'set foldnestmax='.b:max
    :execute 'set foldlevel='.a:level
endfunction
```

Comment: To use alt keys on a Mac: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501092/can-i-map-alt-key-in-vim