# Python: harmless brackets that can be used to collapse/fold multiple lines of code?

Tags: python, atom-editor

Are there any brackets, like "`[]`", "`{}`", "`()`", etc., that can be used in my code so that I can fold multiple lines of variables/defining, without affecting my code?

For example:

```
{
    yes = 1
    no = 0
    maybe = 0.5
}
```

So that I can fold the text to:

```
{...}
```

Comment: No there isn't - if you need more compact definitions you could use other types (e.g. Dict)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A long time ago a plugin existed, allowing using `« code regions »`. These code regions were determined by the format of the comments.

The editor was then able to collapse the code regions with a single click,
but, I think that Python natively does not support this.

Comment: But as you can see elsewhere on slack, somebody prefers not to use code level solutions https://stackoverflow.com/a/360634/1328968 because this can reduce the maintainability of the code.